# get primitive data types from in memory object in python

Tags: python, types

Is there any way to get at the underlying data structures contained in a python object?

I want to get at the underlying data in order to get a unique and unchanging signature of the underlying structure in that object.

For instance, perhaps I have an instantiation of an object in memory that contains a dataframe, a string, and another object

```
class something():
    def init(self, df, string, whatever):
        self.df = df
        self.string = string
        self.whatever = whatever
st = something(...)
```

So of course `something.whatever` could be an instance of an object, which itself would need to be explored to find the underlying data structure.

I came across [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) but I'm not actually sure that's what I'm looking for.

I want to see the underlying primitives so I can hash those primitives or otherwise give it a unique name based upon the structure of the fundamental data. I guess the question comes down to: How do I hash an in-memory object?

Comment: For *serialization*? Or *hashing*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't know the difference, but I assume either one could give me a unique and deterministic name right? If I restart the kernal and run the code again, I'll get the same result, right?

Comment: If you just need a signature, then `hash()` might be all you need.  Have you tried it?  https://www.asmeurer.com/blog/posts/what-happens-when-you-mess-with-hashing-in-python/

Comment: @LexieHankins yes, but you will see that two instances of the same object are actually represented by different hashes. This doesn't help. Furthermore, it also changes everytime you restart the kernel. I'm looking to find a deterministic hash, so that if two instances of the same class and are 'filled' with the same data they have the same hash.

Comment: @LegitStack try `pickle`

Comment: If the output from `pickle` is too lengthy, you could use `hashlib` for reproducible hashes.  Just be sure to use the same salt.

Comment: That instance will have 3 pointers to objects elsewhere in memory - the string, the dataframe, and the unspecified object.  The string is immutable and thus hashable.  The dataframe is mutable, and I'm pretty sure not hashable (numpy arrays are not hashable). That said, I'm not sure what you mean by 'the underlying data structure'.